# How is Barclays Everyday Saver interest rate calculated

Tags: united-kingdom, interest-rate, interest

I searched [online](https://www.barclays.co.uk/savings/instant-access/) and they said it's 0.25%-0.30% per year.
But since my balance is ever-changing, how do they really calculate the interest? Do they just snapshot your balance on a certain day of a year or calculate the average amount, to multiply by interest rate?

Comment: If you follow the **View Account** link on the page you link, you will see it says "_Interest is calculated daily using your statement balance and is paid on the first working day of each month._"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interest is calculated on a daily basis.

There are several algorithms described [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention) how exactly to do that, but roughly spoken, you accrue interest for every day with the balance for that day.

For example, if you put $1000 into your account, keep it there for 20 days, then add $2000 and withdraw $500 the day after, after another 10 days you accrue interest for ($1000 * 20 + $3000 * 1 + $2500 * 10) * p/100/360.

OTOH, if you add $10 every other day, you accrue interest for
($10 * 2 + $20 * 2 + $30 * 2 + …) * p/100/360.